# Universe of a Union of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we take the union of a finite collection $\cup\mathbf{C}$. How do we find a universe that is big enough (is there a "formula" which, given the elements of a collection $\mathbf{C}$, outputs a universe which is big enough?) Is there always such a universe? What if the collection is infinite?

Note: By big enough, I mean that the universe does not exclude results, e.g. suppose $ U =\mathbb{N}$ then $\cup \{\{1,2\}, \{3 ,\pi\}\} = \{x \in \mathbb{N} :x\in \{1,2\} \lor x\in \{3, \pi\}\} =\{1,2,3\}$. $\pi$ is excluded because the universe $\mathbb{N}$ is not big enough.

---

Background:

My textbook states: "Let $X$ be a set and suppose $\mathbf{C}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ (i.e. $\mathbf{C} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$). Then $\cup \mathbf{C}=\{x \in X : \exists C\in \mathbf{C}(x\in C)\}$."
I note that some textbooks do not include the restriction $\mathbf{C} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. Is this restriction given so that $X$ is big enough? Is it implicit in other definitions?

This seems to imply the universe is just the set $X$ for which $\mathbf{C} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$.
For example, let $X=\{0,1\}$. Then $\forall C\in\{\{{0}\},\{1\}\}(C\in\mathcal{P}(X))$ so $\mathbf{C} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$, and thus the universe is $X$.

Moving up a level, we have
$\forall C\in \{\{\{{0}\}\},\{\{1\}\}\}(C\in\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}(X))$  so $\mathbf{C} \subseteq \mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}(X)$, and thus the universe is $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Finally,  $\{\{0\},\{\{1\}\}\} \subseteq \mathcal {P}\{0,\{1\}\}$, and thus $\{0,\{1\}\}$ is a universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard (ZF/ZFC) set theory it is explicitly an **axiom** that whenever $C$ is a *set*, the union $\cup C$ also exists as a set.

This axiom means that we're allowed to consider $\cup C$ as a legitimate set *even though* we cannot describe it as $\{x\in X : \cdots\}$ for any $X$ we already know.

This is an essential axiom of ZF; it cannot be derived from simpler (generally accepted) principles.

If $\cup \mathbf C$ is not known to be a set, the union may not exist, and we may need ad-hoc cleverness to find an $X$ that works.

(Indeed, we can prove that if $\cup \mathbf C$ *is* a set, then $\mathbf C$ is itself a set -- namely $\mathbf C = \{x\in\mathcal P(\cup\mathbf C)\mid x\in \mathbf C\}$ which is a set by the axioms of Power Set and Selection. Thus if $\mathbf C$ is known to be a *proper* class, we also know that $\cup\mathbf C$ is not a set).

Comment: If  we cannot describe it as $\{x\in X : \cdots\}$ for any $X$, why do so many books define it this way?

Comment: @EvanRosica: Good question, though it is not clear to me that _many_ books define it in that way. In axiomatic set theory the closest we come to a definition that looks like that would be $\{x \mid \exists y: y\in C \land x\in y\}$ where the $x$ to the left of the bar is explicitly _not_ restricted and so ranges over all sets.

Comment: Books with the definition you have _probably_ do it because they're trying to enforce some kind of (more or less informal) _type system_ on their set-theoretic expressions, since _in ordinary mathematics_ (that is, outside axiomatic set theory) it is generally a sign of confused thinking and questionable rigor to need to take unions of things you don't already know are in some appropriate universe.

Comment: Now that I look at it, my entry level analysis books (Ross p. 366, Bartle p. 4) as well as Halmos (p. 12) and Enderton (Elements of Set Theory p. 24) omit the universal set and just state it as $\cup \mathbf{C} = \{x:\exists C \in \mathbf{C} (x \in C)\}$. It this a reflection of what you're saying in paragraph 2?